# How can I calculate values for this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

*Disclaimer*: I'm aware this is likely basic math for many on this forum, but I'm lacking in the rudimentary maths needed to even... ask this properly, so I'll just go for it.

For my own curiosity, I'm studying several papers about modelling biological neurons, and am stuck on plotting the [FitzHugh-Nagumo Model](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/FitzHugh-Nagumo_model):

\begin{matrix} 
\dot{V} & = &  V-V^3/3 - W +  I  \\
\dot{W} & = & 0.08(V+0.7 - 0.8W)    
\end{matrix}

I want to know how `V` and `W` evolve over time, where `V` represents a neuron's "voltage", and `W` is a "recovery variable" that is needed to model a neuron's firing pattern (and `I` is a constant, representing a constant current input into the neuron).

As far as I know, `V'` is just the change in `V` over time, so I've tried running the model considering it's evolution over time as `V + V'`, but I think that's too simplistic, and I certainly am not able to generate the plots I'm seeing in the relevant papers.

What do I need to know to get these differential equations into the right form, IE `V = ...` instead of `V' = ...`?

Specifically, I'd love to be able to generate:

- phase diagrams
- and the evolution of `V` (or `W`) over time

Comment: What software do you have available?

Comment: @dbx anything open source, I'm using Haskell, R, python, perhaps Octave (like matlab). I'm comfortable using most anything if I can understand the math.

Comment: Looks like octave has a command called ode45() which will provide numerical solutions.

Comment: @dbx oh awesome, I'll try that out. And any chance you can point me in the right direction for learning the math?

Comment: There's not really a simple answer. It will depend on what you mean by "the math" and is beyond the scope of a stack exchange comment. Differential equations is the field.

Comment: @Josh.F: Here are some notes that might prove helpful http://www4.ncsu.edu/~msolufse/LectureFitzHughNagumo.pdf

Comment: You can plot a rough [phase portrait in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bv-v%5E3%2F3-w%2B2,0.08(v%2B0.7-0.8w)%7D,%7Bv,-2,2%7D,%7Bw,0,4%7D).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a numerical solution I was able to work up in Octave:

```
function result = f(u,t)
  curr = 1;

  V = u(1); W = u(2);

  result = [V-V^3/3-W+curr 0.08*(V+0.7-0.8*W)]
end;

function demo()
  V_0 = 0.7;
  W_0 = 0.7;

  f_handle = @f;

  t = (0:0.1:100);
  u = lsode(f_handle, [V_0 W_0], t);

  V = u(:,1);
  W = u(:,2);

  plot(t, V, 'b', t, W, 'r');
  figure;

end;
```

The workhorse is `lsode` that, as far as I know, just starts from the initial conditions of `V_0, W_0` and evolves the dynamic system forward.